# MAMP - Existing Apache and PHP

Tags: php, apache, mamp

I'm very new to Mac OS, and also to MAMP.

So, Mac OS X comes preloaded with Apache web server, PHP, etc. I have a question regarding installing MAMP:

Will the PHP, Apache, etc that is installed with MAMP replace the preloaded ones? Or, will MAMP install a second instance of each of these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAMP is self-contained and will be run instead of the pre-installed Apache. You'll have to disable the "Web Sharing" feature in the System Settings to disable the builtin Apache server.

Comment: Thanks. What about PHP? Also 2 instances? And, I'll have to disable the preinstalled instance?

Comment: As long as you use PHP only for web sites, you don't need to disable it since it is an apache module and is automatically disabled together with the builtin Apache. Only if you use it on the command line, you need to use the path to the MAMP executable instead of the default one (/usr/bin/php)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the quick and valuable replies!

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't replace anything. MAMP is entirely self-contained. All files live exclusively in the /Applications/MAMP folder and the Apache server runs on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP is self contained. It does not replace the Apache, Mysql or any other thing in the computer or any original settings. It runs these services from its own folder with different port number. The original installation of Apache in MAC OS will continue to run on default port i.e.

Original Apache install will continue to run on
    `localhost:80`

Mamp will install the service on the port port 8888, 8889 for apache, mysql. New MAMP Apache Installation will run on

```
localhost:8888
```

Uninstallation of these services from MAMP is simple as deleting the MAMP folder from applications